# Migrate mysql to MariaDB after Debian 9 upgrade without lose data

Tags: mysql, debian, mariadb

there is a way to migrate to MariaDB without losing database data and leave no package trace after mysql removal?
I get an dependency error while install mariadb-server, other answer has suggested to clean mysql folder then reimport backup, but with short downtime i can't use this method.

I'm on Debian 9.10.
Thanks a lot

Comment: which dependency error ?

Comment: @farbiondriven dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server (--configure): dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Errors were encountered while processing: mariadb-server-10.1 mariadb-server –

Comment: is the problem solved now ?